# Tab key working strangely in Matlab editor?

Tags: keyboard, matlab, tab-key

My Tab key has suddenly started acting strange in Matlab (R2011b) editor. It's working **backwards**!

Pressing it doesn't add tab spaces and whenever I press it after a couple of spaces, the cursor comes back to the first place.

I've checked the keyboard preferences and everything seems fine. Tab action is assigned to the Tab key. Also, turning the autocomplete on/off or changing the Tab size didn't have any effect on it.

Anybody has any idea how to fix this?

**Note:** it's working fine in other applications and also in the console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix for my problem. It was caused by what is called **Emacs-Style Smart Indenting**.

To disable it:

File → Preferences → Editor/Debugger → Tab → "Emacs-style Tab key smart indenting".